# Anaconda 2.7 on Ubuntu not launching

Tags: python, ubuntu, anaconda

I am new with the ubuntu environnement and I am already having some problems. I tried to install anaconda according to my python version but when I try to launch the navigator i get the following errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/toshiba/anaconda2/bin/anaconda-navigator", line 11, in <module>
sys.exit(main())
File "/home/toshiba/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/anaconda_navigator/app/main.py", line 100, in main
clean_logs()
File "/home/toshiba/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/anaconda_navigator/utils/logs.py", line 157, in clean_logs
with open(path, 'w') as f:
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: u'/home/toshiba/.anaconda/navigator/logs/navigator.log'
```

I tried all possible solutions that i found on the net but still has the same problem. i don't know what is wrong. The anaconda navigator cannot be launched and i do not have the anaconda icon on the desktop to launch it directly.

Comment: The traceback indicates a permisson problem. Is `toshiba` your account? Do you have write access to this folder?

Comment: If you are only just learning the basics, you should probably ignore Python 2, and spend your time on the currently recommended and supported version of the language, which is Python 3.

Comment: yes it is my account i do have the access and i tried to download the 3.7 version but still the same problem

Comment: try running it elevated? `sudo anaconda-navigator`

Comment: i tried i get this message " sudo: anaconda-navigator : commande introuvable " and i read that it does not work when using sudo

Comment: How did you install Anaconda?

Comment: i downloaded the installer then run it from terminal using " bash ./Anaconda3-2019.10-Linux-x86_64.sh " at the end of the installation i got "  Thank you for installing Anaconda3! " but no icon for the executable showed